# How to sort the file without delimiter and extract the min and Max value

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

My input file,

```
777aback66789

888gwwww6788

156fhjj88990000

999acvbbnnn788
```

I want to sort the value based on first three char like

```
sort -k1.3,1.3 filename
```

and I want min and max value after sort..

Example the above file I want the result like 
156,999

I want this should happen with single line of Unix command plc help

Comment: will your input lines always have 3-digit number at start or can it have numbers of different length?

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the first 3 characters with `cut`, then sort them with `sort` and then print the first (`1`) and last (`$`) lines with `sed`:

```
cut -c1-3 input.txt | sort | sed -ne '1p;$p'
156
999
```

Comment: hi any chance to have this 156,999

Comment: Just add this to the end `| tr '\n' ','` to translate the newline into a comma.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is your friend

```
awk '{first_three=substr($0,1,3)}
     first_three ~ /^[[:digit:]]{1,3}/{
       if(!min){min=first_three} 
       max = max > first_three?max:first_three;
       min = min < first_three?min:first_three; 
     }
   END{
     print "Minimum : ", min
     print "Maximum : ", max
     }' your_file_name
```

**Sample Output**

```
Minimum :  156
Maximum :  999
```

**Notes**

- `substr($0,1,3) ~ /[[:digit:]]+/` checks the first three characters for digits. This is needed if you have empty lines or non-complying lines in your
  input file
- By default, a newly introduced variable will have a value zero with awk. For `min` though that will not work for obvious reason. So we store its value from the first legal three digit value we get in the statement `if(!min){min=first_three}`

Comment: I am going deal with 5 million records. . Storing into array do u think right option

Comment: @jcrshankar See a more optimized version of my awk program. But i guess this is still a lot resource consuming for a large file. You might try using `perl` or `python` in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

This could be done in one line, but I'll post it here formatted.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$min=-1;
$max=0;
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if(($num) = /^(\d+)/) {
    $max = ($num > $max) ? $num : $max;
    $min = $max if($min == -1);
    $min = ($num < $min) ? $num : $min;
    }

}

print "$min,$max\n";
```

Is this what you meant?

-E

p.s. I think the cut&paste messed up the formatting... such as it was.

```
perl -e '$min=-1;$max=0;while (<>) {chomp;if(($num) = /^(\d+)/) { $max = ($num > $max) ? $num : $max; $min = $max if($min == -1); $min = ($num < $min) ? $num : $min;}  } print "$min,$max\n";'
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort` will do everything you need using the `-k` option and proper `F[.C],F[.C]` choices. In your case

```
$ sort -k1.1,1.3 < dat/sortfile.txt  ## simple redirection of file to sort
156fhjj88990000
777aback66789
888gwwww6788
999acvbbnnn788
```

Above an `F[.C],F[.C]` of `1.1,1.3` says sort beginning on the (`1.1` field `1` - `1st-char`) through (`1.3` field `1` - `3rd-char`).

Once you have `sort` behaving the way you expect it to, all you need is a few lines in a script to find the 3-digit `max/min` from the beginning of each line, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i min=1000
declare -i max=-1000

while read -r line; do 
    [ "${line:0:3}" -gt "$max" ] && max=${line:0:3}
    [ "${line:0:3}" -lt "$min" ] && min=${line:0:3}
done < <(sort -k1.1,1.3 < "${1-/dev/stdin}")  ## process substitution feeds loop

printf "min : %d\nmax : %d\n" "$min" "$max"
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ bash minmax.sh dat/sortfile.txt
min : 156
max : 999
```

**Example Using input from** `stdin`

```
$ printf "777aback66789\n888gwwww6788\n156fhjj88990000\n999acvbbnnn788\n" | \
bash minmax.sh
min : 156
max : 999
```

Lastly, if you want it all as a single command line, then you can do:

```
$ declare -i min=1000; declare -i max=-1000; while read -r line; do \
[ "${line:0:3}" -gt "$max" ] && max=${line:0:3}; \
[ "${line:0:3}" -lt "$min" ] && min=${line:0:3}; done \
< <(printf "777aback66789\n888gwwww6788\n156fhjj88990000\n999acvbbnnn788\n" | \
sort -k1.1,1.3); printf "min : %d\nmax : %d\n" "$min" "$max"
min : 156
max : 999
```

Comment: Why do you use `<` please - is there a `sort` that doesn't take a filename as parameter?

Comment: You can `pipe` to `sort`, you can redirect `<` a file to `sort`, you are simply providing into to sort on `/dev/stdin` regardless how you do it. It's just another way of getting the input to `sort`.

Comment: As an example, here I use `printf` and a `pipe`, e.g. `printf "777aback66789\n888gwwww6788\n156fhjj88990000\n999acvbbnnn788\n" | sort -k1.1,1.3`